# Error when trying to create a Timer in EJB

Tags: java, timer, ejb

I'm having a problem with a timer in **EJB**.I don't have experience whit this type application, so I don't know What to do for resolve this problem.

timer cod:

```
  @Schedule(minute="*/2", second="0", dayOfMonth="*", month="*", year="*", hour="6-23", dayOfWeek="*", persistent = false)
    public void cargaC() {
    ....}



    @Schedule(minute="10", second="0", dayOfMonth="*", month="*", year="*", hour="1", dayOfWeek="*", persistent = false)
        public void limpaTabelaC(){
        ....}
```

error:

```
   18:56:10,103 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 4) JBAS014121: Timer: [id=c7a5c2c9-2b6c-49d8-956a-f831ebab53c3 timedObjectId=PrjX_V2.PrjX_V2.CargaDados auto-timer?:true persistent?:false timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@35d07654 initialExpiration=Wed May 11 06:00:00 BRT 2016 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Wed May 11 18:58:00 BRT 2016 timerState=IN_TIMEOUT will be retried
    18:56:10,103 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 4) JBAS014123: Retrying timeout for timer: [id=c7a5c2c9-2b6c-49d8-956a-f831ebab53c3 timedObjectId=PrjX_V2.PrjX_V2.CargaDados auto-timer?:true persistent?:false timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@35d07654 initialExpiration=Wed May 11 06:00:00 BRT 2016 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Wed May 11 18:58:00 BRT 2016 timerState=IN_TIMEOUT
    18:56:14,813 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 4) JBAS014122: Error during retrying timeout for timer: [id=c7a5c2c9-2b6c-49d8-956a-f831ebab53c3 timedObjectId=PrjX_V2.PrjX_V2.CargaDados auto-timer?:true persistent?:false timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@35d07654 initialExpiration=Wed May 11 06:00:00 BRT 2016 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Wed May 11 18:58:00 BRT 2016 timerState=RETRY_TIMEOUT: javax.ejb.EJBException: Unexpected Error
```

someone can help me?

Comment: Is there no stack trace associated with that `EJBException: Unexpected Error`?  If not, I guess this is a usability bug that you should report.

Answer (score 0):

I think `EJBException: Unexpected Error` is throwed in @timeout method or in automatic timer method.

I think that automatic timers in your question don't produce error. Do you have another programmatic timer? I have seen same log only for programmatic timers:

> Error during retrying timeout for timer: